# What component is a VZ reference designator for

Tags: components, reference

The board I'm looking at is a modem board from a fax machine.

There are 2 identical components labeled VZ1 and VZ2 on the board, both components have F175 on the face and have 2 SMC leads.

One of them has a resistor across the back pins, and they look like they might be part of the power circuitry.

[image: VZ1 and VZ3 visible in the top left and bottom right respectively]

Comment: I was going to guess a Zener, but no strip.. so maybe a TVS (bipolar)

Answer (score 3):

VZ is sometimes used as the designator name for zener diodes.  VZ1 and VZ3 look like 2-lead packages, so that fits.

Take one off the board carefully.  Put a 10 kΩ resistor in series with it, then connect that combination to a power supply, like maybe 24 V.  Measure the voltage across the device, flip it around, then measure the voltage again.  If it is a zener diode, then it will be 700 mV or so in one direction, and some volts in the other.  That latter is the zener voltage.

Comment: I at first thought this too, but there are others labeled DZ, that are obviously through-hole Zener diodes. I'll test it with your method later tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a zener diode: -

[image]

I believe I've seen them called VZ1, VZ2 etc..